# Performing Explicit Route Mapping based upon Web Api v2 Attributes

Tags: asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm upgrading a custom solution where I can dynamically register and unregister Web Api controllers to use the new attribute routing mechanism. However, it seems to recent update to RTM break my solution.

My solution exposes a couple of Web Api controllers for administration purposes. These are registered using the new HttpConfigurationExtensions.MapHttpAttributeRoutes method call.

The solution also allows Web Api controllers to be hosted in third-party assemblies and registered dynamically. At this stage, calling HttpConfigurationExtensions.MapHttAttributeRoutes a second time once the third-party controller is loaded would raise an exception. Therefore, my solution uses reflection to inspect the RoutePrefix and Route attributes and register corresponding routes on the HttpConfiguration object.

Unfortunately, calling the Web Api results in the following error:

"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI".

Here is a simple controller that I want to use:

```cs
[RoutePrefix("api/ze")]
public sealed class ZeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("one")]
    public string GetOne()
    {
        return "One";
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("two")]
    public string GetTwo()
    {
        return "Two";
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("one")]
    public string SetOne(string value)
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Here is the first solution I tried:

```cs
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("ZeApi", "api/ze/{action}");
```

Here is the second solution I tried:

```cs
var type = typeof(ZeController);
var routeMembers = type.GetMethods().Where(m => m.IsPublic);
foreach (MethodInfo method in routeMembers)
{
        var routeAttribute = method.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<RouteAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
       if (routeAttribute != null)
        {
           string controllerName = type.Name.Substring(0, type.Name.LastIndexOf("Controller"));
           string routeTemplate = string.Join("/", "api/Ze", routeAttribute.Template);
           configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(method.Name, routeTemplate);
       }
}
```

I also have tried a third solution, whereby I create custom classes that implement IHttpRoute and trying to register them with the configuration to no avail.

Is it possible to use legacy-style route mapping based upon the information contained in the new routing attributes ?

**Update**

I have installed my controller in a Web Application in order to troubleshoot the routing selection process with the [Web Api Route Debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger.aspx). Here is the result of the screenshot:

[image: Web Api Route Selection in the Route Debugger]

As you can see, the correct action seems to be selected, but I still get a 404 error.

**Update2**

After further analysis, and per Kiran Challa's comment below, it seems that the design of Web Api prevents mixing attribute routing and conventional routing, and that what I want to do is not possible using this approach.

I have created a custom attribute [RouteEx] that serves the same purpose of the Web Api [Route] attribute, and now my code works perfectly.

I guess, since this is not possible using the conventional attribute routing, none of the answers on this question could legitimately be consisered valid. So I'm not nominating an answer just yet.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be required to use reflection and inspect the attribute-routing based attributes yourself. Attribute routing uses existing Web API features to get list of controllers to scan through.

*Question*: Before the switch to attribute routing, how were you loading these assemblies having the 
controllers?

If you were doing this by `IAssembliesResolver` service, then this solution should work even with attribute routing and you should not be needing to do anything extra.

Regarding your **Update**: are you calling `MapHttpAttributeRoutes`?

Comment: I am indeed using MapHttpAttributeRoutes, and this works perfectly fine for controllers builtin to my solution. I cannot call MapHttpAttributeRoutes again for third party plugin controllers, because it raises an exception. So I'm required to use reflection for these additionnal controllers.

Comment: How are you loading the third party plugin controllers into your application...are you having a custom implementation of `IAssembliesResolver`?

Comment: No, I don't because I found out that IAssembliesResolver is only used once (on the first request) and that the result is cached by the WebApi Framework. Therefore, I do assembly resolution and controller selection both in a custom implementation IHttpControllerSelector.

Comment: Upon further analysis, I found that the use of the [Route] attribute is the cause of this solution not working. If I create a custom [RouteEx] attribute and perform reflection on this, it works correctly. I tracked the error to the ApiControllerActionSelector class in the Framework : if the attribute implements IHttpRouteInfoProvider (which the Route attribute does) : the corresponding action is not considered a valid candidate for the current request.

Comment: Interesting scenario. So you are dynamically loading assemblies after the configuration has already been intialized and when a request is received..wondering why isn't it possible for your to load the assemblies at once using assemblies resolver? Regarding your latest comment, that design was deliberate in the sense that conventional routes cannot reach attribute routes.

Comment: OK, then. I'll stay with conventional routes. Thanks for your feedback.